# Can I safely ignore the windows logo testing warning when Installing VirtualBox on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

When I download the xp version of VirtualBox from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/3.0.12/VirtualBox-3.0.12-54655-Win.exe and run it, it alerts me about not being windows logo tested. It then suggests that i stop the installation, or continue at my own risk.

How much of a risk factor is there for this particular product, and has anyone successfully installed it if they got this message as well?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/303234/automatically-accept-windows-logo-testing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should not be a problem.

Drivers have the ability to serious damage to your computer... Basically, anything they want as they get loaded into Windows at a much lower level.

Basically, if you can imagine software being high, if software breaks - it is just a matter of terminating it, where as if a driver crashes, it can bring down the entire machine.

Microsoft offer a lot of testing under the [WHQL (Windows Hardware Quality Labs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHQL_Testing) and it basically means that they guarantee it will work and not crash anything - basically, anything that has the logo is compatible with anything else that has the logo.

There is nothing wrong in using non logo certified devices, but the warning is simply Microsoft's way of saying, don't come to us if it breaks!

Comment: are you done scaring the living daylights out of poor Cyclone? i'm using VirtualBox for years in most of its versions ever released on a variety of Windows operating systems and have yet to experience an 'entire machine' brought down, nevermind the 'serious damage'. :)

Comment: Where have I said anything incorrect?... Re read it, especially my last paragraph

Comment: not saying 'incorrect', just the way you said it almost scared nyself into some psychic trauma :)

Comment: I had to read the whole thing first to make sure you were suggesting I go ahead and do it lol. Thanks, the installation was a success as expected, and I am currently having fun messing with Chrome OS ;)

Comment: Brilliant, and I hope I didn't scare you as Molly thought I may have done!

Comment: You did until I read the whole thing lol. Now to be able to login...it says my login failed lol. (chromeos)

Comment: I installed this as well - you need to use your Google account details... Hope you trust the place you downloaded the image from!!! (Now, that is a warning!)

Comment: I do lol. I have used my google account details for all the ones that I own, none of them seem to login properly xD

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Vbox is perfectly safe? At least one [user recieved the BSOD](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1752) after receiving the warning, but this may have been a fluke. I am not trying to give you a hard time - I rely on using virtual machine    for demonstration, and one of my users got freaked out by this warning. I can't suggest they ignore it without more confidence.

Comment: I created a separate question to more specifically address my issue http://superuser.com/questions/417751/virtualbox-does-not-pass-windows-xp-logo-testing-is-there-a-solution-other-tha

Answer (score 2):

just continue the installtion.

VirtualBox is perfectly safe, the warning you receive is related to the unsigned driver for the virtualbox host-only ethernet adapter.

Comment: Alright. What is the risk factor? What are the chances it could harm my computer?

Answer (score 0):

In most, but not all, cases the warning has been successfully ignored.

However, [VirtualBox ticket 1752](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1752), includes a comment from a user who received the the [Black Screen of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Screen_of_Death) after ignoring the warning.

Ignore at your own risk!